# iOS - How to create static libraries that depends on a core iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I have a core iOS project that has basic stuff. I want to create
static libraries that depends on this core,
But I don't want to distribute two frameworks, I want the static library
with the core project inside it. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make the core project itself a static library (using a different target if necessary) which the other static library depends upon, thus creating one larger static library?